# Jenkins npm start command in background

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, windows-server

How can I use npm start in Jenkins Execute Windows Batch Command to run server in background? This command execute correctly right now but blocked my job. I've tried pm2, Start-Job, forever but it doesn't work. I have to run npm start command in prticular location through Jenkins and my job must to end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
screen -d -m -S screen.npmStart npm start
```

This opens a detached screen with name "screen.npmStart" and executes `npm start` in that screen.

Use `screen -list` to show the available screen sessions.

Execute the following command in your post build action to be sure the screen is killed after your main job has finished.

```
screen -S screen.npmStart -X quit || true
```